# serial port: have to send \n

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

[edit]
Initially I thought this was a pyserial problem but it's not. Basically it's a system problem: Sending anything over the serial port (/dev/ttyS0) would need a "\n" or "\r" or else it'll just be buffered. Below is the original question. Is it a limitation of Linux driver or is there some settings I can change?

Hello there,

I'm trying to use pyserial to write some test code. In reality I'll be transmitting binary data but that's not my problem. My problem is that: it looks like pyserial write() command will only actually send the data when it sees "\n".

Take the following code for sending pure text file.

```
for l in file:
    print "Sending %s" % l
    s.write( l )
    s.flush()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Unless I insert s.write("\n") after s.write( l ), nothing would be seen on the other side. Is there a way I can make pyserial to send whatever I want whenever I want it?

Thanks,

Comment: Looks like a bug in your version of `pyserial`, because `flush` **is** documented as "wait until all data is written" (cfr http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html ). Can you upgrade to pyserial's latest version?

Answer (score 1):

from the documentation for pyserial http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html that does not seem to be the case.  which version are you using?

to clarify, which pySerial and which python seem to be relevant.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 10.04 which says it has 2.3 installed but the actually VERSION string in the module is 1.3.2 (or something). So I upgraded to the latest 2.5 from source.

Comment: From the 'write' method - Changed in version 2.5: Accepts instances of bytes  and bytearray  when available (Python 2.6 and newer) and str otherwise.